# Zend Framework - zf.bat file generates command line error

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line, batch-file

I modified the code of zf.bat file according to my needs but it generates this error
 "***An error has occurred! Action '*' is not a valid action***" on all commands,
How could I solve this?.
Below is the Code of batch file :

```
@ECHO off
REM Zend Framework
REM
REM LICENSE
REM
REM This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
REM with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
REM It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
REM http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
REM If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
REM obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
REM to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
REM
REM Zend
REM Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
REM http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License


REM Test to see if this was installed via pear
SET ZTMPZTMPZTMPZ=@ph
SET TMPZTMPZTMP=%ZTMPZTMPZTMPZ%p_bin@
REM below @php_bin@
FOR %%x IN ("@php_bin@") DO (if %%x=="%TMPZTMPZTMP%" GOTO :NON_PEAR_INSTALLED)

GOTO PEAR_INSTALLED

:NON_PEAR_INSTALLED
REM Assume php.exe is executable, and that zf.php will reside in the
REM same file as this one
SET PHP_BIN=php.exe
SET PHP_DIR=%c:\xampp\php
GOTO RUN

:PEAR_INSTALLED
REM Assume this was installed via PEAR and use replacements php_bin & php_dir
SET PHP_BIN=@php_bin@
SET PHP_DIR=@php_dir@
GOTO RUN

:RUN
SET ZF_SCRIPT=%PHP_DIR%\zf.php
"%PHP_BIN%" -d safe_mode=Off -f "%ZF_SCRIPT%" -- %*
```

I think the error is in last character of last line.

**EDIT: Code of Original FIle**

```
@ECHO off
REM Zend Framework
REM
REM LICENSE
REM
REM This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
REM with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
REM It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
REM http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
REM If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
REM obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
REM to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
REM
REM Zend
REM Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
REM http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License


REM Test to see if this was installed via pear
SET ZTMPZTMPZTMPZ=@ph
SET TMPZTMPZTMP=%ZTMPZTMPZTMPZ%p_bin@
REM below @php_bin@
FOR %%x IN ("@php_bin@") DO (if %%x=="%TMPZTMPZTMP%" GOTO :NON_PEAR_INSTALLED)

GOTO PEAR_INSTALLED

:NON_PEAR_INSTALLED
REM Assume php.exe is executable, and that zf.php will reside in the
REM same file as this one
SET PHP_BIN=php.exe
SET PHP_DIR=%~dp0
GOTO RUN

:PEAR_INSTALLED
REM Assume this was installed via PEAR and use replacements php_bin & php_dir
SET PHP_BIN=@php_bin@
SET PHP_DIR=@php_dir@
GOTO RUN

:RUN
SET ZF_SCRIPT=%PHP_DIR%\zf.php
"%PHP_BIN%" -d safe_mode=Off -f "%ZF_SCRIPT%" -- %*
```

**EDIT: Snapshot of generated error by One Command**
[image]

Comment: If anyone could solve then I'll be grateful to him...

Comment: If you also show what the original .BAT file looked like, I _might_ be able to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Huh? -- You said you modified the BAT file. I need to know what changes you made. That is why I asked for a copy of file _before_ you made changes.

Comment: I just found one solution but not so good and extensible. We can replace the last line with this to accept upto 5 parameters for "zf.php" file in commandline.

    "%PHP_BIN%" -d safe_mode=Off -f "%ZF_SCRIPT%" -- %1 %2 %3 %4 %5

Comment: Look at my expanded answer. It might help diagnose why %* is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your modified code:

```
SET PHP_DIR=%c:\xampp\php
```

To this:

```
SET "PHP_DIR=c:\xampp\php"
```

***Edit - I just realized the extra % in your original modification is getting stripped out by the parser anyway, so the above suggestion couldn't help.***

---

Restore the last line to its original form with %* at end - this should expand to all command line arguments. But it is not working for you. To find out why, add a new line `ECHO ON` immediately before the restored last line.

Now run the script and look at how the last line is being interpreted. If you can't figure out why it's not working, post the result.

Comment: I'm getting this output: "php.exe" -d safe_mode=Off -f "c:\xampp\php\zf.php" -- * An error Has Occurred Action '*' is not a valid action.

Comment: Using my method i.e. %1 %2 %3 ... instead of %* satisfied my needs of creating a tree structure of zend project in netbeans. So, No problems now.

Comment: @user950146 - Very odd. The %* works on my machine (of course the command fails since I don't have the software installed, but %* expands properly). The only way I can get your result is if I add a space between % and * at the end of the last line.